# RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout inside NestedScrollViewLayout cannot scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with collapsing toolbar and a nested scroll view with a `FrameLayout` that I place the fragments in it. Initially, I place in it a `FragmentA` with a  **CardView** .

Works great. When I click a button though I replace that `FragmentB` with another one containing a  **RecyclerView** .

When I add the `FragmentB` I cant scroll to the bottom of the list.

**Host Activity Layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        .........
          ......
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <!-- the layout which will be the content of the activity (which will be hosted inside the drawer (NOT the list of the drawer)) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**FragmentB Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_users"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_progress"
        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_retry"
        />

    <!--</LinearLayout>-->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Already answered in first answer...

Comment: change the recycler view's height to match_parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put `RecyclerView` inside the `NestedScrollView`.
I think better solution is to have `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView` but not both, because `RecyclerView` is already implementing `NestedScrollingChild`.

I have similar layout in my app. I did the same - put RecyclerView to FrameLayout and then inside the NestedScrollView. It's stop to work correctly. Without NestedScrollView everything works fine.

Comment: Problem is not `RecyclerView with NestedScrollview`, but `SwipeRefreshLayout with NestedScrollview`! `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollview` can work together.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First of all you don't have to embed your fragment container in `NestedScrollView` if you want a scrolling behavior in your activity.

Put `FrameLayout` directly into Coordinator layout with `layout_behavior` attribute in it, then simply put any fragment with scrolling View (and it don't have to have layout_behavior attr).

So in your example you should have to fragments:

`FragmentA` that has layout with CardView inside NestedScrollView
`FragmentB` with RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Other problem is that you put more then one child in `SwipeRefreshLayout`, and as stated in documentation it should have only **one** direct child. [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is scrollevent problem,customview extends ListView or RecycleView.
this is my sol:

```
public class RewriteListView extends ListView {


    public RewriteListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
    }


    public RewriteListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
    }


    public RewriteListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
```

}

be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Already answered! Two scrollable elements (such as RecycleView and NestedScrollView in your question) can't work together.

Edit your Activity layout.

```
<ParentLayout>

.......

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        .........
          ......
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

//THIS FRAGMENT WILL BE REPLACED!
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

.......
</ParentLayout>
```

And than by default, in first run of this activity - replaced FrameLayout above - to your first fragment with NestedScrollView (You need to create new Fragment for replacing) and after click replacing to Fragment in your Question.

Comment: Problem is not `RecyclerView with NestedScrollview`, but `SwipeRefreshLayout with NestedScrollview`! `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollview` can work together.